# Difference between stylesheet_directory and template_directory

Tags: themes, child-theme, parent-theme

What is the differene between stylesheet_directory and template_directory? Is that representing Child theme and Parent theme?

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 10):

Kind of - the `template_directory` is the directory of your parent theme. The `stylesheet_directory` is the directory containing the primary stylesheet in use (which, if you have a child template will be the in the child directory, otherwise it will be in the template directory).

See the [Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo):

**'stylesheet_url'** - Returns the primary CSS (usually style.css) file URL of the active theme.

**'template_url' / 'template_directory'** - URL of the active theme's directory ... Within child themes, both `get_bloginfo('template_url')` and `get_template()` will return the parent theme directory.